# Clicks from AdWords are not reported in Google Analytics despite linked account

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have a Google Analytics view that's linked to an AdWords account, and I'm wanting to display clicks (especially by campaign) in Google Analytics. The problem is that clicks are only reporting for Remarketing campaigns, not for any "standard" search campaigns.

The link appears to be good, and those RM clicks are reporting. Is there anything that would prevent the standard campaigns from reporting clicks?